# Sorting by key in a multidimensional array with php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting, ksort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059255/sorting-multidimensional-array-in-php)

How can I sort by key in a multidimensional array?

For instance, below is the array I print from my db, where the **latest** comes first - **December, November, October, etc** and **2011, 2010, 2009, etc**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [URL] => september 2011
            [Title] => September 2011
            [Date] => 8
            [Month] => 9
            [Year] => 2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [URL] => january 2011
            [Title] => January 2011
            [Date] => 1
            [Month] => 2
            [Year] => 2011
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [URL] => february 2011
            [Title] => February 2011
            [Date] => 4
            [Month] => 1
            [Year] => 2011
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [URL] => november 2011
            [Title] => November 2011
            [Date] => 23
            [Month] => 11
            [Year] => 2010
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [URL] => april 2011
            [Title] => April 2011
            [Date] => 23
            [Month] => 4
            [Year] => 2010
        )

)
```

But I need it to be like this, **October, November, December, etc** and **2011, 2010, 2009, etc** - note the months are sorted by the **oldest** comes first but the years are still sorted by the **latest** comes first.

So the array should be sorted like this,

```
Array
(

    [2] => Array
        (
            [URL] => february 2011
            [Title] => February 2011
            [Date] => 4
            [Month] => 1
            [Year] => 2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [URL] => january 2011
            [Title] => January 2011
            [Date] => 1
            [Month] => 2
            [Year] => 2011
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [URL] => september 2011
            [Title] => September 2011
            [Date] => 8
            [Month] => 9
            [Year] => 2011
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [URL] => april 2010
            [Title] => April 2010
            [Date] => 23
            [Month] => 4
            [Year] => 2010
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [URL] => november 2010
            [Title] => November 2010
            [Date] => 23
            [Month] => 11
            [Year] => 2010
        )
)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generic solution to sort arrays of arrays with multiple keys

Based on my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5198276/50079), here is a very generic solution that you can use in lots of situations.

**Limitation:** Requires PHP >= 5.3 to work, due to the presence of anonymous functions.

### New and improved, now with descending sort support

```
function make_comparer() {
    $criteriaNames = func_get_args();
    $comparer = function($first, $second) use ($criteriaNames) {
        // Do we have anything to compare?
        while(!empty($criteriaNames)) {
            // What will we compare now?
            $criterion = array_shift($criteriaNames);

            // Used to reverse the sort order by multiplying
            // 1 = ascending, -1 = descending
            $sortOrder = 1; 
            if (is_array($criterion)) {
                $sortOrder = $criterion[1] == SORT_DESC ? -1 : 1;
                $criterion = $criterion[0];
            }

            // Do the actual comparison
            if ($first[$criterion] < $second[$criterion]) {
                return -1 * $sortOrder;
            }
            else if ($first[$criterion] > $second[$criterion]) {
                return 1 * $sortOrder;
            }

        }

        // Nothing more to compare with, so $first == $second
        return 0;
    };

    return $comparer;
}
```

### How to use it

To sort by year ascending:

```
uasort($array, make_comparer('Year'));
```

To sort by year ascending, then by month ascending:

```
uasort($array, make_comparer('Year', 'Month'));
```

To sort by year descending, then by month ascending:

```
uasort($array, make_comparer(array('Year', SORT_DESC), 'Month'));
```

This last one is what you 're after.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: You 're welcome, I hope you find many uses for it.

Comment: +1 for more generic solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data you would have provided in your question would have been actually correct (taking Year, Month, Date as base to create a sort on), you can first index the array by those values and the sort the main array. I'm just writing it, otherwise you might misread the output of the [Demo](http://codepad.org/AesDmKr3), the URL/Titles do not correspond to the numerical values given, but it just works:

```
// create an index by date
foreach($data as $k=>$v)
{
    $index[$k] = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $v['Year'], $v['Month'], $v['Date']);
}

// sort data based on the index
array_multisort($index, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Data:

```
$arr = Array (
    Array (
        'URL' => 'september 2011',
        'Title' => 'September 2011',
        'Date' => 8,
        'Month' => 9,
        'Year' => 2011,
    ),
    Array (
        'URL' => 'january 2011',
        'Title' => 'January 2011',
        'Date' => 1,
        'Month' => 2,
        'Year' => 2011,
    ),
    Array (
        'URL' => 'february 2011',
        'Title' => 'February 2011',
        'Date' => 4,
        'Month' => 1,
        'Year' => 2011,
    ),
    Array (
        'URL' => 'november 2011',
        'Title' => 'November 2011',
        'Date' => 23,
        'Month' => 11,
        'Year' => 2010,
    ),
    Array (
        'URL' => 'april 2011',
        'Title' => 'April 2011',
        'Date' => 23,
        'Month' => 4,
        'Year' => 2010,
    ),
);
```

code:

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    if ($a['Year'] == $b['Year']) {
      return ($a['Month'] - $b['Month']);
    } else {
        return ($b['Year'] - $a['Year']);
    }
}    
usort($arr, 'compare');
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [URL] => february 2011
        [Title] => February 2011
        [Date] => 4
        [Month] => 1
        [Year] => 2011
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [URL] => january 2011
        [Title] => January 2011
        [Date] => 1
        [Month] => 2
        [Year] => 2011
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [URL] => september 2011
        [Title] => September 2011
        [Date] => 8
        [Month] => 9
        [Year] => 2011
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [URL] => april 2011
        [Title] => April 2011
        [Date] => 23
        [Month] => 4
        [Year] => 2010
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [URL] => november 2011
        [Title] => November 2011
        [Date] => 23
        [Month] => 11
        [Year] => 2010
    )

)
```