# Sort rows of a 2d array with a particular "sticky" value in a column first, then sort by another column ascending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, sticky

I want to sort an array by 'hits', but I also want to look for a particular ID and set that as the first iteration, then continue the 'hits' sort.

For example, I have a multidimensional array:

```
$myarray = [
    ["id" => 10, "hits" => 80],
    ["id" => 14, "hits" => 50],
    ["id" => 15, "hits" => 700],
    ["id" => 18, "hits" => 200],
];
```

I want to test whether the id is something particular, i.e. if the id==18 then put it first, then sort by hits. How would I do this, using usort and a custom function?

I think I'm looking for something similar to:

```
function customsort($a,$b) {
    if ($a["id"] == 18) { //or b == 18?
        return -1;
    } else {
        return $a["hits"] > $b["hits"];
    }
}

usort($myarray, "customsort");
```

The outcome I would like is for the order to be:

```
[
    ["id" => 18, "hits" => 200],
    ["id" => 14, "hits" => 50],
    ["id" => 10, "hits" => 80],
    ["id" => 15, "hits" => 700],
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Multiple uasort functions breaks sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198276/php-multiple-uasort-functions-breaks-sorting)

Comment: Duplicate of lots of questions really, but the one above has a turnkey solution (I know because it's mine).

Comment: so you just need to change $a["hits"]>$b["hits"];
 to return $a["hits"]>$b["hits"];

Comment: I dont want to sort by ID then Hits, I want to look for one particular ID then order the rest by Hits... if that makes sense.

Comment: Seems like a simple case of writing a custom comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing in your code that might make this NOT work is the `return $a["hits"]>$b["hits"];`. Your function should return 1/-1 only (not true/false), so change that line to: `return $a["hits"]>$b["hits"]?1:-1;` and it should work as expected.

Sure enough, it works: http://codepad.org/ItyIa7fB

Comment: Oh awesome!! Thanks! Don't I have to also compare $b["id"] though where I've put the comment?

Answer (score 0):

PHP's sorting functions all expect a "3-way comparison".  Since the "spaceship operator" entered the language there are very few reasons to manually make greater than and less than comparisons.

For your scenario with two sorting criteria, compare two values on each iteration of the callback.  In the first check if the `id` value IS NOT `18` -- because `false` is "less than" `true`.  This way, any row with `18` will come first, then all of the rest will be sorted by the secondary rule.

When sorting with the spaceship operator, for ascending sorting use `$a <=> $b` comparisons.  For descending, use `$b <=> $a` comparison.  Each rule may use ascending or descending rules.

See also:

- [Properly sorting multidimensional array using usort and spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309755/2943403)
- [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175345/2943403)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Iu9Cg))

```
usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => [$a['id'] !== 18, $a['hits']]
                  <=>
                  [$b['id'] !== 18, $b['hits']]
);
var_export($array);
```

If your PHP version is below 7.4, here is an equivalent script which works down to PHP5.3. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/npfhm)

```
usort(
    $array,
    function ($a, $b) {
    return ((int) ($a['id'] !== 18) - (int) ($b['id'] !== 18))
           ?: $a['hits'] - $b['hits'];
    }
);
```

---

Alternatively, `array_multisort()` can be used; it just needs a preparatory loop to populate sorting arrays of equal size.  This snippet works all the way down to PHP4.3.0 [Demo](https://3v4l.org/4QmP9)

```
$sticky = array();
$hits = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $sticky[] = $row['id'] !== 18;
    $hits[] = $row['hits'];
}

array_multisort($sticky, $hits, $array);
var_export($array);
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me

Comment: @Max I've added another snippet which is suitable for PHP4.3.0 and higher.