# PHP array sort by value and date (2 columns)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have multidimensional array in PHP. Something like

```
$mylist = array(
    array('ID' => 1, 'title' => 'Hello', 'datetime' => '2014-05-05 12:08 PM'),
    array('ID' => 2, 'title' => 'Amazing Pic', 'datetime' => '2014-05-06 11:08 PM'),
    array('ID' => 3, 'title' => 'Style', 'datetime' => '2014-05-02 9:08 PM'),
    array('ID' => 4, 'title' => 'Hello World', 'datetime' => '2014-05-01 5:08 PM')
);
```

My question is how do I sort by title and datetime? I spent quite some time searching on this. But I just found sort by two columns but with the same data type. I am now struggling to do this because I believe mine involve strtotime() function as this involves time.

This is what I have at this moment

```
function querySort ($x, $y) {
    return strcasecmp($x['title'], $y['title']);
}

function cmp($a, $b){
    $ad = strtotime($a['datetime']);
    $bd = strtotime($b['datetime']);
    return ($ad-$bd);
}

usort($mylist , 'querySort');

usort($mylist , 'cmp');
```

Could anyone help me on how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the output right now?

Comment: Another thing: It is not possible to sort by two parameter. If you sort by title and then by datetime, the result wont be different from a sort with only datetime.

Comment: @MarkGabriel I have tried using `array_multisort()` but ended up with only title is sorted correctly but not the date time

Comment: I found some solutions even in SO itself, it is possible to sort by more than one parameters. it is just that my parameter involves date time format, so this is little bit tricky for me.

Comment: Well according to this code, your array is sorted according to the title and then, you sort it according to the datetime. So the first sorting is useless. The output you get is an array which is sorted according to the datetime.

Comment: @Xl-lord that's correct. It is useless. So I am looking if I can sort by both columns.

Comment: Don't put the answer in your question.

Comment: @Jack noted, i will post them as an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59190916/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `usort` overrides the output of the first `usort`.

What you need to do is merge the 2 sorting functions to order themselves by title and then date time.

Pseudocode would be :

```
function SortByTitleAndDateTime($a,$b)
    1) SortByTitle and return the value if it is non zero.
    2) If SortByTitle is zero (meaning the 2 values are the same in terms of title), 
        do SortByDateTime
```

In the end, you'd only need to call `usort(array, SortByTitleAndDateTime)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need array_multisort. You can visit following link for more information http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

The basic idea would be cleared from example#2 on above link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$mylist = array(
    array('ID' => 1, 'title' => 'Hello', 'datetime' => '2014-05-05 12:08 PM'),
    array('ID' => 2, 'title' => 'Amazing Pic', 'datetime' => '2014-05-06 11:08 PM'),
    array('ID' => 3, 'title' => 'Style', 'datetime' => '2014-05-02 9:08 PM'),
    array('ID' => 4, 'title' => 'Hello World', 'datetime' => '2014-05-01 5:08 PM'),
     array('ID' => 5, 'title' => 'Boy', 'datetime' => '2014-05-01 5:08 PM')
);


// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($mylist as $key => $row) {
    $dTime[$key]  = $row['datetime'];
    $title[$key] = $row['title'];
}

// Sort the data with dTimedescending, titleascending
// Add $mylist as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($dTime, SORT_DESC, $title, SORT_ASC, $mylist);
```

Your output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [title] => Amazing Pic
            [datetime] => 2014-05-06 11:08 PM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [title] => Hello
            [datetime] => 2014-05-05 12:08 PM
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [title] => Style
            [datetime] => 2014-05-02 9:08 PM
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [title] => Boy
            [datetime] => 2014-05-01 5:08 PM
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [title] => Hello World
            [datetime] => 2014-05-01 5:08 PM
        )

)
```

I have added ID no 5 for demonstration, so that date wise sorted in descending order and title wise sorted in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like Mark Gabriel's logic. This will sort out the title first, and followed by the date time. So here it is:

```
function SortByTitleAndDateTime($a,$b){
    if ( strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']) != 0 ){
        return strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    }
    else{
        $ad = strtotime($a['datetime']);
        $bd = strtotime($b['datetime']);
        return ($ad-$bd);
    }
}
usort($mylist, 'SortByTitleAndDateTime');
```

Hope this helps other people as well.