# Output an array in alphabetical order

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of users like this one:

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 246
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Doe 
        )
   [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 246
            [name] => Mark
            [surname] => Doe 
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [id] => 246
            [name] => Bill
            [surname] => Buffalo 
        )
)
```

Id like to have an output like this:

```
<h4>B</h4>
 Buffalo Bill
<h4>D</h4>
 John Doe
 Mark Doe
```

How can I accomplish this result?

Comment: read up on the `usort()` function, and all the similar questions listed on the right hand side of this page.

Comment: I don't need to order the array, but only to group each surnames under the first letter of the surname.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587997/sort-array-value-in-alphabetical-order?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$group = array_reduce($data, function($a,$b) { $a[$b['surname']{0}][] = $b; return $a; } );
ksort($group);

foreach($group as $id => $data)
{
    printf("<h4>%s</h4>\n",$id);
    foreach($data as $name)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n",$name['name'],$name['surname']);
    }
}
```

Output

```
<h4>B</h4>
Bill Buffalo
<h4>D</h4>
John Doe
Mark Doe
```

[See Full Demo](http://eval.in/4306)

Comment: **Downvoter** can you give a reason ?