# Sort multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

I have multidimensional array, for exaple this:

**$mas = array("s",array("c","b","a"),array(3,5,1),"a",array("s",array("z","a")));**

I want sort (ascending) all array-elements, i write recursive function, but it is not working, please tell me, who I have a wrong ?

```
$mas = array("s",array("c","b","a"),array(3,5,1),"a",array("s",array("z","a")));



function sortsort($m) {
    sort($m);
    foreach ($m as &$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
             sortsort($v);
        }
    }
    return $m;
}



  var_dump(sortsort($mas));
```

Comment: If you change the definition from `sortsort($m)` to `sortsort(&$m)`, does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$mas = array("s",array("c","b","a"),array(3,5,1),"a",array("s",array("z","a")));
function sortsort(&$m) {
    sort($m);
    foreach ($m as $k=>$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
             sortsort($m[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $m;
}

print_r(sortsort($mas));
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
  $sorter=array();
  $ret=array();
  reset($array);
  foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
      $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
  }
  asort($sorter);
  foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
      $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
  }
  $array=$ret;
}
```

aasort($your_array,"order");