# AWS Cloudwatch PHP SDK returning unsorted metrics statistics

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I am currently extracting CloudWatch metrics statistics with the aws php sdk.

Unfortunately the getMetricStatistics method is returning unsorted results. I wonder why it is not sorted by Timestamp ASC. Does anyone know how to get sorted results from Cloudwatch?

my code

```
$result = $this->client->getMetricStatistics(array(
        'Namespace'  => 'My.Namespace',
        'MetricName' => 'my-metric',
        'StartTime'  => strtotime('-1 days'),
        'EndTime'    => strtotime('now'),
        'Period'     => 300,
        'Statistics' => array('Average'),
));
```

and the result

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Timestamp' => string '2014-04-16T10:53:00Z' (length=20)
      'Unit' => string 'Count' (length=5)
      'Average' => string '9.998594711316002' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Timestamp' => string '2014-04-16T11:43:00Z' (length=20)
      'Unit' => string 'Count' (length=5)
      'Average' => string '0.7908148450858722' (length=18)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Timestamp' => string '2014-04-16T11:08:00Z' (length=20)
      'Unit' => string 'Count' (length=5)
     'Average' => string '5.402251656252796' (length=17)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Timestamp' => string '2014-04-16T11:03:00Z' (length=20)
      'Unit' => string 'Count' (length=5)
      'Average' => string '8.958888493053081' (length=17)
```

Thanks for your help!

J.

#### UPDATE

I still did not manage to get sorted results directly from the method call. So I used usort as suggested by @Svenskunganka

```
usort($result['Datapoints'], function($a, $b) {
    if($a['Timestamp'] == $b['Timestamp']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['Timestamp'] < $b['Timestamp']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

I am still looking for the perfect way to get sorted results. If anyone has a clue, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Have you tried using the [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function? Here's a good example in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11774832/1765851)

Comment: sure i could use usort to sort the array afterwards, but when there is a possibility to get sorted results directly from the method call this would be much better

Comment: As far as I know, the `getMetricStatistics` function does not take any other parameters. Although it's odd that it would return an unsorted array when you want get data in a given time frame. Your best bet would be to use the `usort` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get sorted results from GetMetricStatistics, you have to sort the datapoints yourself.

> "GetMetricStatistics does not return the data in chronological order."
>
> Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html