# PHP sorting 3 dimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I know this would be an easy one but I don't get it. All answered I found on the net was... too complex to me, maybe.

Here is my typical array:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Conversation' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'created' => '2012-08-04 00:00:00'
    ),
    'ConversationUser' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2'
        )
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Conversation' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'created' => '2012-08-01 00:00:00'
    ),
    'ConversationUser' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2'
        )
    )
));
```

I want to sort my data with ['Conversation']['created'] date, asc or desc.

Any simple answer ? :P

P.S. I can't use MYSQL sort, I retrieve the data one by one and create that array.

Comment: You may want to read up on [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort). You'll just have to code a little function to do the array access and date comparison then.

Comment: `P.S. I can't use MYSQL sort, I retrieve the data one by one and create that array.` The two do not contrast each other. You can use MySQL sort **and** iterate the results one by one to create the array. Please share your query with us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php) :

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b){
    $a = strtotime($a['Conversation']['created']);
    $b = strtotime($b['Conversation']['created']);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: I believe you can simply return `$a - $b`, and even skip the temporary variables altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to do this:

```
// $data is your array from the example
// first obtain the rows for sorting
$sortkeys = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $sortkeys[] = $row['Conversation']['created'];
}

// sort $data according to $sortkeys
array_multisort($sortkeys, $data);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: the best and the most universal answer in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) and [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) functions, which let you customize the way arrays are sorted.

Either the solution is simple or complex, remember what Einstein said once: "*Things should be always done as simple as possible, but never simpler than they really are*".

If you have some trouble with these functions, we can give you further clues ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort()`](http://uk.php.net/usort) (or, to maintain index association, [`uasort()`](http://uk.php.net/uasort). Example: (assumes your array is `$arr`):

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return
    preg_replace('/\D/', '', $b['Conversation']['created'])
    >
    preg_replace('/\D/', '', $a['Conversation']['created']);
});
```

That will sort descending. Change `>` to `<` for ascending.