# sort and merge multidimensional arrray based on sub-array values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

i need to sort and merge a complicated array! array is multidimensional and sub arrays use 2 key/values like this:

```
<?php
$result = array(
array("1", "20"),
array("1", "33"),
array("2", "10"),
array("2", "25"),
array("2", "7"),
array("3", "33"),
array("3", "80"),
array("4", "300")
);
print_r($result);
?>
```

now i need to sort it based on aggregation of key[1] values (in sub-arrays) where values of keys[0] is similar and merge then sort it from more to less! for example in above i like result to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 113
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 53
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 42
        )

)
```

i hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: i was read all of them! this is not like my problem, why you just take negative point on questions!? i'm afraid to make a question in this SO :)

Comment: Right, you first need to divide your problem. The one part is to do the aggregation and the second part is to do the sort. But both really has been covered.

Comment: maybe you are right, i'm not good enough in arrays, i searched every where to solve it myself, but i couldn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is the `array_multisort` function, but it requires some work to get the input in the right format. Have a look at the code below. First we accumulate the values, then split it in an index array and a value array, sort it with multisort and merge it back together.

```
$result2 = array();
foreach($result as $pair) {
    if  (!isset($result2[$pair[0]]))
        $result2[$pair[0]] = 0;
    $result2[$pair[0]] += $pair[1];
}
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach($result2 as $key => $value) {
    array_push($array1, $key);
    array_push($array2, $value);
}
array_multisort($array2, SORT_DESC, $array1);
$result3 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    array_push($result3, array($array1[$i], $array2[$i]));
}
print_r($result3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you can compact the two operations (aggregate sums, create the sort array) into one iteration.

However the code becomes hard to read:

```
list($sort, $result) = array_reduce($result, function($a, $v) {
    $a[1][$v[0]] = [$v[0], (@$a[0][$v[0]] += $v[1])];
    return $a;
}, []);

array_multisort($sort, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $result);
```