# PHP Multidimensional array custom sort

Tags: php

PHP Multidimensional array custom sort.

Sort should be based on values in field `[position]`
A person can have multiple positions (see the special case listed below).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Secretary
            )
    )
)
```

I want the array to be ordered on position values as

1. General Secretary
2. President
3. Treasurer
4. Secretary
5. Committee Member

**Special case**
for the below array, it should be the first array. Because this person is "General Secretary"

```
[2] => Array
(
    [person_id] => 51136
    [position] => Array
        (
            [0] => General Secretary
            [1] => Committee Member
        )

    [person_name] => Person 1
)
```

**Example input data**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 22180
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Secretary
            )
        [person_name] => Person 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 51135
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => President
            )
        [person_name] => Person 2
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 51136
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => General Secretary
                [1] => Committee Member
            )

        [person_name] => Person 3
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 44141
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Treasurer 
            )

        [person_name] => Person 4
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 51137
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Committee Member
            )
        [person_name] => Person 5
    )
)
```

**Output required**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 51136
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => General Secretary
                [1] => Committee Member
            )

        [person_name] => Person 3
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 51135
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => President
            )
        [person_name] => Person 2
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 44141
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Treasurer 
            )

        [person_name] => Person 4
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 22180
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Secretary
            )
        [person_name] => Person 1
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 51137
        [position] => Array
            (
                [0] => Committee Member
            )
        [person_name] => Person 5
    )
)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2

Comment: check this out...
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: I can't use descending or ascending type. see the portion in question **"I want the array to be ordered on position values as"**

Comment: You can still use `usort()`, just compare two person by `array_search($position,array(5=>"General Secretary",4=>"President"...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I make this out.

You can still use `usort()` instead of re-inventing the wheel. Just compare two person by the position like `array_search($position,$pos_array)`.

```php
function sortByPosition($ps)
{
    $pos=array(0=>"General Secretary",1=>"President",2=>"Treasurer",3=>"Secretary",4=>"Committee Member");
    usort($ps,function($p1,$p2) use ($pos){
        $lvl1=count($pos);
        $lvl2=count($pos);
        foreach($p1["position"] as $position)
        {
            $lvl1=min(array_search($position,$pos),$lvl1);
        }
        foreach($p2["position"] as $position)
        {
            $lvl2=min(array_search($position,$pos),$lvl2);
        }
        return $lvl1-$lvl2;
    });
    return $ps;
}
```

Test:

```php
$arr=Array(Array("person_id" => 22180,"position" => Array("Secretary"),"person_name" => "Person 1"), Array("person_id" => 51135,"position" => Array("President"),"person_name" => "Person 2"), Array("person_id" => 51136,"position" => Array("General Secretary","Committee Member"),"person_name" => "Person 3"), Array("person_id" => 44141,"position" => Array("Treasurer"),"person_name" => "Person 4"), Array("person_id" => 51137,"position" => Array("Committee Member"),"person_name" => "Person 5"));
print_r(sortByPosition($arr));
```

Outputs:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 51136
            [position] => Array
                (
                    [0] => General Secretary
                    [1] => Committee Member
                )

            [person_name] => Person 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 51135
            [position] => Array
                (
                    [0] => President
                )

            [person_name] => Person 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 44141
            [position] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Treasurer
                )

            [person_name] => Person 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 22180
            [position] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Secretary
                )

            [person_name] => Person 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 51137
            [position] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Committee Member
                )

            [person_name] => Person 5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Quicksort, or any other sorting algorithm, and just make sure the comparison takes place on the right variable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

From Wiipedias pseudocode you could du this by changing the 7th line to just check the position parameter of your arrays.

```
function quicksort('array')
      if length('array') ≤ 1
          return 'array'  // an array of zero or one elements is already sorted
      select and remove a pivot value 'pivot' from 'array'
      create empty lists 'less' and 'greater'
      for each 'x' in 'array'
          if 'x' ≤ 'pivot' then append 'x' to 'less' // change to x['position'] and pivot['position']
          else append 'x' to 'greater'
      return concatenate(quicksort('less'), 'pivot', quicksort('greater')) // two recursive calls
```