# Sorting multidimentional Array Keys As Number

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, sorting

I'm having a problem to sort multidimensional array.

`print_r($myarray);` is giving following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [Code] => 12-111
            [Name] => putup1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 11
            [Code] => 12-21
            [Name] => putup2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 12
            [Code] => 12-1
            [Name] => putup2
        ) 
  )
```

I took a reference from this link: [Sort MultiDimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2) and sorted using column `Code`. it given me output like this:

```
Array
    (
      [0] => Array
                 (
                  [ID] => 10
                  [Code] => 12-1
                  [Name] => putup1
                 )
      [1] => Array
                 (
                   [ID] => 12
                   [Code] => 12-111
                   [Name] => putup2
                 ) 
      [2] => Array
                 (
                   [ID] => 11
                   [Code] => 12-21
                   [Name] => putup2
                 )
     )
```

And I expecting output like :

```
Array
        (
          [0] => Array
                     (
                      [ID] => 10
                      [Code] => 12-1
                      [Name] => putup1
                     )
          
          [2] => Array
                     (
                       [ID] => 11
                       [Code] => 12-21
                       [Name] => putup2
                     )
         [1] => Array
                     (
                       [ID] => 12
                       [Code] => 12-111
                       [Name] => putup2
                     ) 
         )
```

Is it possible? Please suggest me...
Thank you :)

Comment: The link you posted is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php. This is likely a duplicate of that as well.

Comment: So, do you want to sort by [Code] length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently sorting on code, but as text and not as a number. To sort it as you want, you have to write a comparison function that indicates whether one code is bigger than another:

```
function sortByCode($a, $b) {
    $aParts = explode('-', $a['Code']);
    $bParts = explode('-', $b['Code']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aParts); $i++) {
        if ($aParts[$i] < $bParts[$i]) {
            return -1;
        } else if ($aParts[$i] > $bParts[$i]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

usort($myArray, 'sortByCode');
```