# Sort value of array from low to high in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A1
            [tongdiem] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A2
            [tongdiem] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A3
            [tongdiem] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A4
            [tongdiem] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A5
            [tongdiem] => 21
        )

)
```

And I need sort [tongdiem] ASC, but not change array key, this like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A1
            [tongdiem] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A2
            [tongdiem] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A3
            [tongdiem] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A5
            [tongdiem] => 21
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [lop] => 7A4
            [tongdiem] => 30
        )

)
```

I have tried asort, some php array build-in function, but not working.

I need sort array with [tongdiem] value ASC, but not change array key.

How do I do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['tongdiem'] == $b['tongdiem']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['tongdiem'] < $b['tongdiem']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, "cmp");
```