# sort a html table with in the code in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple html table within PHP.
Here is my code:
      
     
        
        
        Chart
        
        -->

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="chart">
            <h2>No. of Files Uploaded to Knowledge Base</h2>
            <table id="data-table" border="1" cellpadding="10"     cellspacing="0">


            <tr>
                    <td>Users</td>
                    <td>Project Files</td>
                    <td>Process Files</td>
                    <td>System Files</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
            </tr>   

                        <?php

                        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/project/');
                        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                        $pos = 15;
                        $file = substr("$filename", +$pos); 

                        $lenght = strlen($file);
                        $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                        $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);
                        if($file1 != '.DS_Store'){

                            $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM Project WHERE location = '$file'");

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                                $occurance1 = $row['uploader'];
                                $array1[] = $occurance1; 
                                }
                            }                           
                        }




                        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/process/');
                        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                        $pos = 15;
                        $file = substr("$filename", +$pos);                         
                        $lenght = strlen($file);
                        $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                        $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);

                        if($file != '.DS_Store'){

                            $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM Process WHERE processlocation = '$file'");

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                                $occurance2 = $row['uploader'];
                                $array2[] = $occurance2; 
                                }
                            }                           
                        }

                        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/system/');
                        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                        $pos = 14;
                        $file = substr("$filename", +$pos);                         
                        $lenght = strlen($file);
                        $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                        $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);
                        if($file != '.DS_Store'){

                            $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM System WHERE location = '$file'");

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                                $occurance3 = $row['uploader'];
                                $array3[] = $occurance3; 
                                }
                            }                           
                        }

                        $uploader = mysql_query("Select username from members");
                        while($Load = mysql_fetch_array($uploader)){
                        $value = $Load['username'];
                        $tmp = array_count_values($array1);
                        $cnt = $tmp[$value];
                        echo"<tr>";
                        echo"<td>$value</td>";
                        echo "<td>$cnt</td>";


                        $value2 = $Load['username'];
                        $tmp2 = array_count_values($array2);
                        $cnt2 = $tmp2[$value2];

                        echo "<td>$cnt2</td>";

                        $value3 = $Load['username'];
                        $tmp3 = array_count_values($array3);
                        $cnt3 = $tmp3[$value3];
                        $total = $cnt + $cnt2 + $cnt3;
                        echo "<td>$cnt3</td>";
                        echo "<td>$total</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";

                        ?>

            </table>
    </div>

          </body></html>
```

The users are populated from a database table. The file figures are populated by reading and counting the amount of files in the directory.
I want to be able to automatically sort the table by the total figure so the user with the highest total figure will be on top and first and so on..so it will look similar to a league table.

I do not know how to do this.
Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Put the information in an array, sort the array, and then create the HTML from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you save it into the database as well?

```
SELECT uploader FROM Project WHERE location = '$file' ORDER BY field
```

Otherwise, I would just get the database query for all users into an array using `mysql_fetch_array`, iterate over them and count the files, and store this value into the array.

Then order the array (like "[Sort multidimensional Array by Value (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2)") and iterate it again to output.

Comment: The data that OP wants to sort is not in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing everything inline, store all data in an array, then you can use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array. Then simply loop through the array to echo values.

```
$table_rows = array(); //add this
$counter = 0; //add this
while($Load = mysql_fetch_array($uploader)){
    //...more code here but not going to put everything
    $counter++;
    $table_rows[$counter] = array();
    $table_rows[$counter]['username'] = $value;
    $table_rows[$counter]['project'] = $cnt;
    //...more code here but not going to put everything
}

function cmp_rows($a,$b) {
    if ($a['total'] == $b['total']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['total'] > $b['total']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($table_rows,'cmp_rows');

foreach($table_rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>";
    //...more code here but not going to put everything
}
```

Comment: How would I store all the data that is already i variables in an array?

Comment: Updated answer above to show you how to store array and sort array and display array.

Comment: Thanks!Although this code doesnt work as it should - the names of the users are being pulled form the database. Can you explain the code to me and then I could maybe make changes myself?

Comment: Yeah inside your while loop where you pull the data out of the database you have echo's that display username, project count, etc... instead of echoing those values store them in to the $table_rows array like i gave an example in my code.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So I should keep "$value = $Load['username'];
       $tmp = array_count_values($array1);
       $cnt = $tmp[$value];"?

Comment: Yeah but instead of echoing them store them into the array.

Comment: Ok thanks. The usernames and project prints correctly but the process does not.I presume this has something to do with the $value, $value2 variables both being 'username'.What do you think?

Comment: Did you add them into the array like I did for username and project in the example? I didn't do everything for you I was just giving you an example. You need to store $cnt2 $cnt3 and $total in the array.

Comment: I know, sorry, I realised I had made a mistake in typing my code.This was a great help!Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know how I would make the first row a different colour for the highest user?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

According to your requirement best way to get this done is to get the sorted results from the database as below.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ORDER BY field_name desc
```

**Method 2**

You can sort the result set using PHP functions like `array_multisort`. Read the below links for examples. Few links are shown below. Google for more links.

http://shiflett.org/blog/2011/jun/sorting-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-php

[Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2)

[How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

[How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

**Method 3 - Optional : Just For Your Information**

You can use [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) which is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library to sort the table as required.