# Sorting multi-dimensional array based on value of specific key in array

Tags: php

I have an array which is something like this:

```
    $array[] = array(
        "name" => "sample",
        "image" => "sample.jpg",
        "header" => "sampleDelights",
        "intro_copy" => ""
    );
    $array[] = array(
        "name" => "lwmag",
        "image" => "lwmag.jpg",
        "header" => "LW Mag",
        "intro_copy" => ""
    );
```

I want to sort this array based on the alphabetical order from the key "header" with PHP. I have tried usort and searched for built in functions but cannot find one (or looking past it). Is this possible with a single php function?

Comment: http://php.net/usort, check out example #2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at "ksort"

it is very useful for arranging an array by its key.

```
<?php
$sample = array("d" => "maximum", "a" => "minimum", "c" => "mid")
ksort($sample);
foreach ($sample as $key => $val) {
echo "$key = $val \n";
}
?>
```

that would display

```
a = minimum
c = mid
d = maximum
```

hopefully that's what you're after.

Source: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this function from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php#99419)

```
function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```