# Is it possible to sort an array using secondary values contained in its primary index?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

hey guys i have a bit of a chicken or egg problem. I query an ldap database for a list of users and recieve a 2-dimensional array in the form

`Array[index]['username']`

The ldap database is currently not sorted alphabetically, or at least records are not being retrieved in an alphabetic order, so using a for loop on the `[index]` returns an unsorted looking list.
How can i sort my `Array` alphabetically by the values in  'username'?
is this even possible(easily)? :O

Comment: usort() is the function you'll need

Comment: http://php.net/ldap_sort

Comment: Or of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's loads of duplicates for that... but here you go:

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){ return strcmp($a['username'], $b['username']); } );
```

Comment: I did search quite a bit before asking. Perhaps the language i was using to search was off.. Many thanks