# php 2d array sorting with unique

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got this array:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => new@particip.pl
                [challs] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => new@email.pl
                [challs] => 551
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => new@email.pl
                [challs] => 551
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => new@email.pl
                [challs] => 553
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => new@email.pl
                [challs] => 553
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => info@mail.com
                [challs] => 
            )

    )
```

How make this to array with unique email addresses and joined challs, for ex in this case:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => new@particip.pl
            [challs] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => new@email.pl
            [challs] => 551, 553
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => info@email.com
            [challs] => 
        )

)
```

Can be it sorted, or I need to do forach inarray? Someone had idea how to do it?

Comment: got idea how to do it?

Comment: You can use array multisort take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/96870/1287608

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something along the line of the following is what you want:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    if (! isset($result[$array['id']])) {
        $result[$array['id']] = array(
            'id' => $array['id'],
            'challs' => $array['chall']
        );
    }

    if (! in_array($result[$array['id']]['challs'], $array['chall'])) {
        $result[$array['id']]['challs'] .= ', ' . $array['chall'];
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: close, but it's not it, I got: Array ( [new@particip.pl] => Array ( [id] => new@particip.pl [challs] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [new@id.pl] => Array ( [id] => new@id.pl [challs] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [info@cowonder.com] => Array ( [id] => info@cowonder.com [challs] => Array ( [0] => ) ) )

Comment: What do you get? I believe the only difference is that the resulting array is indexed by the email addresses instead of 0, 1, 2, etc. Or is the problem that challs in the resulting array is an array instead of a string?

Comment: I updated my answer, the resulting array is now zero-indexed and chall is a string with the values separated by comma's.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailsSeen = array();

foreach($array as $key => &$item) {
    if(in_array($item['id'], $emailsSeen) {
        //concatenate 'challs' of repeated email to first occurence of email in $array
        $array[array_search($item['id'], $emailsSeen)]['challs'] .= ', ' . $item['challs'];
        //remove duplicate email item from $array
        unset($array[$key']);
    } else {
        $emailsSeen[$key] = $item['id'];
    }
}

//To reindex the array
$array = array_values($array);
```