# Sort array by date in descending order by date in php

Tags: php

I have an array and I want to sort it by date. I am not able to sort it properly by date in descending order. Please help.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 11/05/2013
        [2] => Executive Planning Day
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 13/06/2013
        [2] => Middle Leaders Planning Day
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 12/07/2013
        [2] => New Staff Induction Day
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [1] => 13/04/2013
        [2] => Staff Conference Day No. 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [1] => 14/04/2013
        [2] => Staff Conference Day No. 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [1] => 15/02/2013
        [2] => Staff Conference Day No. 3
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [1] => 16/03/2013
        [2] => Australia Day
    )
)
```

Comment: Maby have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 22):

Try like this

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a[1]) - strtotime($b[1]);
}
usort($data, "sortFunction");   //Here You can use asort($data,"sortFunction")
```

or you may try by detail like(its just suggestion)

```
function sortFunction($a,$b)
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) return 0;
    return strtotime($a[1]) - strtotime($b[1]);
}
usort($data,"sortFunction");
```

As the **strtotime is not obey d/m/Y format** try like this

```
$orderByDate = $my2 = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$row)
{
    $my2 = explode('/',$row[1]);
    $my_date2 = $my2[1].'/'.$my2[0].'/'.$my2[2];        
    $orderByDate[$key] = strtotime($my_date2);  
}    
array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Comment: "date"-index does not exist

Comment: I like this answer.
@bestprogrammerintheworld that's because in the OP's array the date is indexed as '1', not as 'date'. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Gautam3164 - It's ok, it was just to clarify :-)

Comment: @mkumpan - I know and Gautam has changed it accordingly :-) I like the answer to.

Comment: i try this but not getting data in descending format. Date ordering still not correct :(.

Comment: getting incorrect data after using your suggestions : Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 11/05/2013 [2] => Middle Leaders ) [1] => Array ( [1] => 10/05/2013 [2] => Executive Planning Day ) [3] => Array ( [1] => 25/06/2013 [2] => New Staff Induction Day ) [4] => Array ( [1] => 27/06/2013 [2] => Year 8-12 commence ) [6] => Array ( [1] => 23/06/2013 [2] => Executive Planning Day )}

Comment: Yup it is working for me but data sorting is in ascending order. I want it in descending order. like higher date should be on top of array then lower and lower.

Comment: See the third one,it will related to you bec your time is in d/m/Y formate

Comment: @neerajsharma now check is it working or not...consider third ans of mine

Comment: I was testing with that. It is working for me now.; thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I spent a night working on how to do this for my own similar issue.  To sort an associative array by date of a key in that array.

Both usort and [uasort](https://www.php.net/uasort) require a sort function that you must write and pass as the second parameter.  The sort function is used by usort and uasort to compare each item in the array and store the result as $yourArray

```
 function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
           return strtotime($a[1]) - strtotime($b[1]);
 }

 uasort($yourArray, "sortFunction");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use usort(Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function).

```
usort($array, function($a1, $a2) {
   $value1 = strtotime($a1['date']);
   $value2 = strtotime($a2['date']);
   return $value1 - $value2;
});
```

Comment: getting incorrect data after using your suggestions :

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 11/05/2013
            [2] => Middle Leaders
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10/05/2013
            [2] => Executive Planning Day
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 25/06/2013
            [2] => New Staff Induction Day
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 27/06/2013
            [2] => Year 8-12 commence
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [1] => 23/06/2013
            [2] => Executive Planning Day
        )}

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions but data is not coming in properly descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) return 0;
    return (strtotime($a[1]) < strtotime($b[1])) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($data, "cmp");
```

Comment: getting incorrect data after using your suggestions : Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 11/05/2013 [2] => Middle Leaders ) [1] => Array ( [1] => 10/05/2013 [2] => Executive Planning Day ) [3] => Array ( [1] => 25/06/2013 [2] => New Staff Induction Day ) [4] => Array ( [1] => 27/06/2013 [2] => Year 8-12 commence ) [6] => Array ( [1] => 23/06/2013 [2] => Executive Planning Day )}

Comment: @neerajsharma Your dates are not in [proper format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). You can replace that by a `preg_match()`. However, it might be more time-efficient to go once through `$data` and add a timestamp to each item before sortin, so that this conversion is done only once per item.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely happy with all of the answers here so I thought I'd mention that if you wish to sort an **associative** array preserving the keys then you should use [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/uasort) rather than [`usort`](https://www.php.net/usort).  You can also parse the date from any format you like with the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/datetime) library which also includes some [predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for some of the standard formats.

```php
uasort($array, function($a, $b){ 
    $format = 'd/m/Y'; 
    $ascending = false;
    $zone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $a[1], $zone)->getTimestamp();
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $b[1], $zone)->getTimestamp();
    return $ascending ? ($d1 - $d2) : ($d2 - $d1);
});
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/5MjoTZ)

Answer (score 2):

I jumped here for associative array sorting and found this amazing function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php. This function is very dynamic that sort in ascending and descending order with specified key.

Simple function to sort an array by a specific key. Maintains index association.

```
<?php

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

$people = array(
    12345 => array(
        'id' => 12345,
        'first_name' => 'Joe',
        'surname' => 'Bloggs',
        'age' => 23,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12346 => array(
        'id' => 12346,
        'first_name' => 'Adam',
        'surname' => 'Smith',
        'age' => 18,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12347 => array(
        'id' => 12347,
        'first_name' => 'Amy',
        'surname' => 'Jones',
        'age' => 21,
        'sex' => 'f'
    )
);

print_r(array_sort($people, 'age', SORT_DESC)); // Sort by oldest first
print_r(array_sort($people, 'surname', SORT_ASC)); // Sort by surname
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd build an array for ordering.

```
$ordered = array();
foreach ($planning as $event) {
  $ordered[$event['date']] = $event;
}
ksort($ordered);
```

Comment: This is going to come down around your ears if the array contains a few hundred thousand entries.

Comment: Or if two fields have the same date.

Comment: mkumpan: because hydrating few hundred thousand entries considering the structure he has will be much more performant, right?

Comment: My array doesn't have the date index name then how it will work ??. I am not getting correct data.

Comment: use `$event[1]` in this case

Answer (score 1):

so do it like this:

```
//your array


$arr = array();
array_push($arr, array("11/05/2013", "Executive Planning Day"));
array_push($arr, array("13/06/2013", "Middle Leaders Planning Day"));
array_push($arr, array("12/07/2013", "New Staff Induction Day"));
array_push($arr, array("13/04/2013", "Staff Conference Day No. 1"));
array_push($arr, array("14/04/2013", "Staff Conference Day No. 2"));
array_push($arr, array("15/02/2013", "Staff Conference Day No. 3"));
array_push($arr, array("16/03/2013", "Australia Day"));


var_dump($arr);

function sortDateDesc($a, $b){  
    $strA = implode("-", array_reverse( explode("/", $a[0]) ) ); 
    $strB = implode("-", array_reverse( explode("/", $b[0]) ) ); 

    return strtotime($strB) - strtotime($strA);
}



usort($arr, "sortDateDesc");

var_dump($arr);
```

If your date format is constant day/month/year then you need to pass it in a string format recognized by the parser and year-month-day is an ISO standard if I remember it well, that one works fine

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example with the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) `<=>`

```
    $array = Array(
        Array(
            "id" => "1",
            "date_time_rdv" => "2018-02-22 11:29:35",
        ),
        Array(
            "id" => "2",
            "date_time_rdv" => "2020-02-13 10:05:25",
        ),
        Array(
            "id" => "3",
            "date_time_rdv" => "2019-02-15 22:18:45",
        )
    );

    function date_compare($a, $b) {
        $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
        $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $a['date_time_rdv']);
        $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $b['date_time_rdv']);
        return $d2 <=> $d1;
    }

    usort($array, 'date_compare');
```

It will output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date_time_rdv] => 2020-02-13 10:05:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [date_time_rdv] => 2019-02-15 22:18:45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [date_time_rdv] => 2018-02-22 11:29:35
        )

)
```

If you use `uasort()` instead, it will output this (it will maintain index association)

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date_time_rdv] => 2020-02-13 10:05:25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [date_time_rdv] => 2019-02-15 22:18:45
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [date_time_rdv] => 2018-02-22 11:29:35
        )

)
```

If you try `return $d1 <=> $d2;`, it will reverse the order.

In `date_compare()`, we use `DateTime::createFromFormat` which parses a time string according to a specified format. You could use the format you need, like in the op question `dd/mm/YYYY`

More info on [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) :

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Gautam3164 is almost perfect. You need to change the format of the dates.
I'd say:

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$a[1])) - strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$b[1]));
}
usort($data, "sortFunction");   //Here You can use asort($data,"sortFunction")
```

11/10/1987 -> 10 Nov 1987
11-10-1987 -> 11 Oct 1987

Answer (score 0):

```
$sortdate = array(
    '17/08/2015',
    '02/01/2017',
    '05/02/2014'
);

function sortFunction($a, $b)
    {
    $datea = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $a));
    $dateb = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $b));
    if ($datea == $dateb)
        {
        return 0;
        }

    return ($datea < $dateb) ? -1 : 1;
    }

usort($sortdate, "sortFunction");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($sortdate);
```

Comment: A little explanation of what you've done would be helpful.