# order an array by greatest date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
( [0] => 03-11-2013 [1] => 04-09-2016 )
```

How do I order it so that the greatest date always comes first?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried anything or do you expect us just to write your code?!

Comment: Use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a comparison callback that converts formatted dates to unix timestamps so that they can be compared easily

Comment: gazillion posts about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733128/sort-array-by-date-in-descending-order-by-date-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', $array), SORT_DESC, $array);
```

Convert to timestamps and sort descending, sorting the original array.  Might be better to have them as timestamps or `YYYY-MM-DD` if you control the array creation.