# php | Multidimensional array sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array and need to be sorted (based on id):

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Name1
        [sku] => Model 1
        [options] => 
        [price] => 100.00
    )
   [1] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 2
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Name2
        [sku] => Model 1
        [options] => Color: <em>Black (+10$)</em>. Memory: <em>32GB (+99$)</em>. 
        [price] => 209.00
    )

)
```

Is it possible to sort my array to get output (id based)?

```
 Array
    (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [qty] => 2
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Name2
        [sku] => Model 1
        [options] => Color: <em>Black (+10$)</em>. Memory: <em>32GB (+99$)</em>. 
        [price] => 209.00
      ) 
    [1] => Array
      (
        [qty] => 1
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Name1
        [sku] => Model 1
        [options] => 
        [price] => 100.00
      )
 )
```

Thanks!

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: This also looks like a result from a database query. Isn't this better handled by using an `ORDER BY` clause in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$id_arr = array();
foreach ($my_arr as $key => $value)
{
    $id_arr[$key] = $value['id'];
}
array_multisort($id_arr, SORT_DESC, $my_arr);
```

You can also place `SORT_ASC` for assending order.Better you add `ORDER BY id` to the query through which you are getting this array of results

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a["id"] - $b["id"];
}
usort($arr, "cmp");//$arr is the array to sort
```