# Unsort in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Good day.

I would be like get 3 keys from $arr where value $arN[0] will be more than other...

Code:

```
$ar1=array(201,281);
$ar2=array(1252760,1359724);
$ar3=array(452760,34349724);
$ar4=array(1260,134344);
$ar5=array(232750,1359724);
$ar6=array(60,1439724);

$arr[]=array(6299927 => $ar1);
$arr[]=array(1252760 => $ar2);
$arr[]=array(3432444 => $ar3);
$arr[]=array(3435543 => $ar4);
$arr[]=array(7645466 => $ar5);
$arr[]=array(4574534 => $ar6);
```

Next function sorting array $a descending:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
outpoot: 0:6 1:5 2:4 3:2 4:1
```

But how change this function for my example(for my  big array)?

Tell me please how make this?

How write right?

Comment: Do you want to get the index, if 201 is greater than 281 or 201 is greater than 1252760?

Comment: What do you mean by "unsort"? Is that a typo for "usort"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @Starx 201 is greater than 1252760

Comment: @Barmar yes whis usort

Comment: This is a very strange array. Each element of the array is an associative array with just one element with a different key. Why don't you use those as the keys of `$arr`?

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing but I think you are looking for something like this. It will give you the index of the array whose first item is greater than the first item in the next array.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $array) {
    if($array[0] > $arr[$key+1][0]) {
       echo $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex, Of course my code is working. I think you meant, you are not getting the result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    $subkeys = array_keys($row); // Elements are one-element associative arrays
    $dates[$key]  = $row[$subkeys[0]][0]; // Get the element, then get its [0] sub-element

}
array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ans_array= array();

            // for shuffle array without repeat
            for($q=0;$q<count($arr);$q++)
            {
                $n = rand(0,count($arr));
                if($ans_array[$n] == NULL || $ans_array[$n] == '')
                {   
                     $ans_array[$n] = $arr[$q];
                }
                else
                {     if($q==0) $q=0;
                      else $q = $q-1;
                }
            }
```