# sort data in alphabetical order using php

Tags: php

I get the data from database and I want to sort `hotel_name` in alphabetical order. How can I do it using php's `sort` function or any other method ?

```
foreach($selData as $row)
{
    $name=$row['hotel_name']; 
    $distance_colombo=$row['distance_colombo'];
    $distance_airport=$row['distance_airport'];
    $description=$row['description'];
    $activities=$row['activities'];
    $str=(explode(',',$activities));
    print_r($str);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `ORDER BY hotel_name` on your SQL query?

Comment: Did you seriously not find anything when you typed "php sort" into Google?

Comment: @cHao kindly replace Google with Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: prix, i alredy use order by in sql query i',s work fine... @cHao i got bunch of sort functions and i try to do that way.. what i'm asking is i don't want to sort whole array..i want only sort 'hotel_name' coulumn only using sort function... i get some errors doing using sort functions

Comment: @PrabathAnuradha: If all you want is the `hotel_name` column, then create an array with just that in it, and `sort($that_array)`.  Otherwise, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2699086 (which was the 5th result in Google, BTW, so don't tell me you bothered), which is itself marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/96759 .

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort) here. Just use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) in your SQL query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY hotel_name
```