# How can I retrive the top 3 rated events MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have sporting events that users can rate. All data is stored in a Mysql database.

Ratings_table:

```
rating_id PK 
organization float //subrating
value_for_money float //subrating
fun_factor float //subrating
facilities float //subrating
event_id int
user_id int
```

Event_table:

```
event_id PK
event_name varchar
```

Is there a way I can use Mysql query to join the tables and order them so that I can retrieve the 3 events with the highest average rating of the sub ratings?

Comment: Do you want to get the 3 highest ratings, or do you want to get the 3 with the highest average ratings? I think you want the later, but your question asks for the former.

Comment: I want to get the top 3 events by the average of the 4 sub ratings.

Comment: What you want is probably easier to do in PHP than a single query. Whilst it is possible to do in one query, the query will be very complicated.

Comment: How might I do it using PHP please?

Comment: I'm typing up an answer now, check back in 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be it:

```
SELECT e.event_id, event_name, avg_rating
FROM Event_table e
JOIN (
    SELECT event_id, MAX((organization+value_for_money+fun_factor+facilities)/4) avg_rating
    FROM Ratings_table
    GROUP BY event_id
    ORDER by avg_rating DESC
    LIMIT 3) r
ON e.event_id = r.event_id
```

Comment: Huh, much simpler than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a very complex query to do it all in one single mysql query. Personally I would do this in PHP. This is an example of how you can do it in PHP and MySQLi

```
$ratings = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM ratings";
$results = $dbConn->query($query);
//First we load all results into a big array.
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc($results) {
    if(!isset($ratings[$row['rating_id']]) {
        $ratings[$row['event_id']]['count'] = 0;
    }
    $ratings[$row['event_id']]['count']++;
    $ratings[$row['event_id']]['organisation'] += $row['organisation'];
    $ratings[$row['event_id']]['value_for_money'] += $row['value_for_money'];
    $ratings[$row['event_id']]['fun_factor'] += $row['fun_factor'];
    $ratings[$row['event_id']]['facilities'] += $row['facilities'];
}
//Now we go through each event and average out the results.
$averages = array();
foreach($ratings as $event_id => $data) {
    $averages[$event_id]['organisation'] = $data['organisation'] / $data['count'];
    $averages[$event_id]['value_for_money'] = $data['value_for_money'] / $data['count'];
    $averages[$event_id]['fun_factor'] = $data['fun_factor'] / $data['count'];
    $averages[$event_id]['facilities'] = $data['facilities'] / $data['count'];
}
//Now we can sort by whatever we want to:
```

Alternatively if you want the average across all 4 ratings you can use this bit on the end instead for the averages:

```
$averages = array();
foreach($ratings as $event_id => $data) {
    $averages[$event_id] = (($data['organisation'] + $data['value_for_money'] + $data['fun_factor'] + $data['facilities']) / 4) / $data['count'];
}
```

**Please note: I have not tested this code... you should check it for bugs yourself.**

For sorting, please check various stack overflow answers on sorting multidimensional arrays. [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2)
or [How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
distinct r.eventId
from 
ratingTable r
inner join eventTable  e on (r.eventId=e.eventId)
order by rating_id limit 3
```

But it also can be achieved by

```
Select 
    distinct r.eventId
    from 
    ratingTable r
    inner join eventTable 
order by rating_id limit 3
```

Comment: Why are you ordering by rating_id? He wants it ordered by the average rating.