# sort multidimensional array by values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array fetched from mysql database tables of type. I want to sort it in order of particular value.

```
$arr1=array(array(12, 8, 5, 34),
        array(54, 87, 32, 10),
        array(23, 76, 98, 13),
        array(53, 16, 24, 19));
```

How can i sort it by value?
Like sorting by 2nd value should result to.

```
$arr1=array(array(12, 8, 5, 34),
        array(53, 16, 24, 19),
        array(23, 76, 98, 13),
        array(54, 87, 32, 10));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php), then again, if you fetch it from a database, the database probably can do it faster for you...

Comment: [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) is your friend.

Comment: @Wrikken: `array_multisort` is one of those functions that I've never quite figured out how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to solve these problems.

```
$sortKey = 1;
usort($arr1, function($a, $b) use($sortKey){
    return $a[$sortKey] - $b[$sortKey];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Got to agree with @RocketHazmat, [`array_multsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is a royal pain in the backside.  `usort` is much easier to follow but I thought I'd have a go anyway:

```
$sortKey = 1;
array_multisort(array_map(function($v) use($sortKey){
    return $v[$sortKey];
}, $arr1), $arr1);
```

It only took 20 minutes... :(

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/2rZYIz): http://ideone.com/2rZYIz