# Showing the ouput of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am pretty new in php. I am trying to print a data from an array.I have googled for it but can't find any solution yet.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2  [university_name] => UNIV_NAME [university_id] => 1 [year] => 2010 )
```

Here i want to print just the "UNIV_NAME ".How can i get UNIV_NAME as output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @tinyByte I see nothing about sorting in this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $array[0]->university_name
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you have an a array

```
$a = array("num"=>"1","university_name"=>"My University","id"=>"2","Year"=>"2013");
```

For displaying

```
echo $a['university_name'];
```

here "university_name" is the index of the array.