# php - sort multi dim assoc array by specific value

Tags: php

```
$data['rows'][1] = array('id' => '1', 'cell' => array('branch' => 'ANT', 'type' =>     'deliver', 'dateTime' => '2014-02-07 01:01:01'));
$data['rows'][2] = array('id' => '2', 'cell' => array('branch' => 'ANT', 'type' =>     'deliver', 'dateTime' => '2014-02-06 01:01:01'));
$data['rows'][3] = array('id' => '3', 'cell' => array('branch' => 'GB2', 'type' =>     'deliver', 'dateTime' => '2014-02-07 02:02:02'));
```

I want to sort `$data['rows']` descending based on `dateTime`. How can I do that?

Comment: Before answers come flooding in, if you are getting this data out of the database it would be easier to order it at that point (`order by dateTime desc`). If not then no problem

Comment: have look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: @webnoob these array came from 4 tables so i have to sort it in an array. is there a way to sort an array in php just like mysql does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function [usort](http://php.net/usort) will serve your purpose:

```
usort($data["rows"], function($a, $b){
return strcmp($a["cell"]["dateTime"], $b["cell"]["dateTime"]);
});
```

Note that the above code will sort the array in ascending order. For descending order replace `function($a, $b)` with `function($b, $a)`.

Comment: i used your answer and its works but i dont know how it works haha. And where do i specify the order type, if DESC or ASC?

Comment: thanks man. it worked perfectly. But still i dont get how it worked hahha.

Comment: You’re welcome. If you want to know how it worked, visit the link to the PHP manual provided in my answer.