# PHP Using Usort to sort a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, usort

I've seen similar questions, I simply do not understand the answers. Hopefully if I ask specifically about my code something will click. I've been stuck for some time and would really appreciate the help.

I have an array:
    foreach ($showresult as $display)
    {
    $display_result[] = array        ('parkid' =>$display['parkid'],

```
                 'trailsys' =>$display['trailsys'],

                         'trailset' =>$display['trailset'],

                         'name' =>$display['name'], 

                         'description' =>$display['description'], 

                         'url' =>$display['url'], 

                                 'ldes' =>$display['ldes'],

                                 'ltxt' =>$display['ltxt'],

                         'address' =>$display['address'], 

                         'city' =>$display['city'], 

                         'zip' =>$display['zip'], 

                         'phone' =>$display['phone'], 

                         'pos' =>$display['pos'],   

                         'T1' => $display['systemname'],

                 'T2'=> $display['name']);

 {                           'state' =>$display['state'],
```

Every item in the array has a value in T1. T2 can have a value, or it can be 0. I want to alphabetize the list by T1. In some cases, there will be three or four entries where T1 is the same, then I want to alphabetize those by T2. I'm stumped.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with usort() function ( http://www.php.net/usort ). It allows you to sort array  by custom function. So, in your case it would be something like:

```
<?
  usort($array,function($a,$b) {
    if ($a['T1'] < $b['T1']) return -1;
    elseif ($a['T1'] > $b['T1']) return 1;
    else {
      if ($a['T2'] < $b['T2']) return -1;
      elseif ($a['T2'] > $b['T2']) return 1;
      else return 0;
    }
  });
?>
```

You could check it out and adjust to your needs.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Okay, Here's where I feel stupid. What do $a and $b represent?

Comment: Well they represent two elements of the `$array`. That's how `usort()` works.

Comment: $a and $b are each item in the array.

Comment: I get the following error:
Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/ride4w5/public_html/test_site/test.php on line 59

Comment: Well your `$array` is null. What is the variable holding your array?

Comment: Is your array variable called $array?

Comment: Ha! That's why I feel stupid. I changed it to the correct array name and it works. I still have so much to learn. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am glad I can be of help.

Comment: Wait, that's close. This sorts alphabetically by T1, or T2 if there is a value. What I want is for it to alphabetize by T1 ALWAYS but if there is more than one entry with the same T1 value, then to alphabetize those by T2.

Comment: This sorts by T2 if T1 are equal. You could either, sort once by T1, then sort some of the elements again by T2. Or you could create an array, like `$ts = Array()` and then populate it with `T1` in the `usort()` function. Then you check if `T1` exists in `$ts` and sort by `T2`, else add it to array and sort by `T1`.