# Sorting a multidimensional array by child array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort an array like this

```
     [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [stats] => Array
                    (
                        [SessionsPlayed] => 1
                    )

            )
     [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 88
                [stats] => Array
                    (
                        [SessionsPlayed] => 6
                    )

            )
     [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [stats] => Array
                    (
                        [SessionsPlayed] => 9
                    )

            )
```

So that it is in descending order by the SessionPlayed column like this.

```
     [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [stats] => Array
                    (
                        [SessionsPlayed] => 9
                    )

            )
     [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 88
                [stats] => Array
                    (
                        [SessionsPlayed] => 6
                    )

            )
     [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [stats] => Array
                    (
                        [SessionsPlayed] => 1
                    )

            )
```

I have attempted to look online on how to solve this but all of the answer I find can only sort down one child ( ex. the id column ) 
Here are the posts I looked at.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16788610/1319033
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699110/1319033

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['stats']['SessionsPlayed'] - $a['stats']['SessionsPlayed'];
    // $b - $a for descending order
});
```

Comment: The way I showed here. `usort` sorts an array and uses an user-defines comparing function