# sort json or multi dimensional array data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have checked the site and there are tons of answers relevant to this question. But i am learning PHP. So, it is quite hard for me to understand. 
Anyways,

```
$data = array();
$data['count'] = $result->num_rows;
...
...
$data['content'][] = array(
                    "userid" => $userid,
                    "title" => $title,
                    "slug" => $slug,
                    "download" => $download,
                    "usrtitle" => $usrtitle,
                    "company" => $company,
                    "period" => $period,
                    "email" => $email,
                    "mobile" => $mobile,
                    "fname" => $fname,
                    "lname" => $lname,
                    "address" => $address,
                    "pic" => $pic,
                    "appliedon" => date("d-M-Y", strtotime($appliedon)),
                    "price" => $price
                    );
echo json_encode($data);exit;
```

I am using ajax to fetch data from database. Everything is working fine but i want to sort data by price. I can't hard code it because i want user to select the same.
There are nested mysql queries and it is not possible to sort the data from mysql query. Because data are coming from multiple queries.

Please advise how can i sort the data.

I found this question on SO [How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) 
I am not sure this will work in my case or not.

Thanks

**Edit:**
database table structure.

`userid, title, slug,email,mobile,fname,lname,address,pic` is coming from users table. `download, usrtitle, company,price` coming from profile table. `appliedon` coming from apply table.

First query run on appliedon table from there i get userid. this userid used in users and profile table to fetch the details. I am not sure i can use orderby clause to sort the data here.

Comment: sort the data in mysql query itself

Comment: please show your query. It will give you sorted data.

Comment: There are nested mysql queries and it is not possible to sort the data in mysql query. Because data are coming from multiple queries.

Comment: ORDER BY clause is used to sort particular columns inside database queries..

Comment: @MohammedShafeek i have updated the question. Hope this will make more sense.

Comment: is $userid,$title, etc.. all these things are array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP built in function `array_multisort` is work for this case.

1.Get an array of prices  coming from `$data['content']`

```
$sort_arr = array();
foreach($data['content'] as $item) {
    $sort_arr[] = $item['price'];
}
```

2.Use `array_multisort` to sort `$data['content']` by price in descent order:

```
//if you want ascending order replace `SORT_DESC` by `SORT_ASC`
array_multisort($sort_arr, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $data['content'])
```

More detail of `array_multisort` usage, see official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Comment: Didn't tried yet. As i am away from my machine. Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and define own sort function:

```
$data = [
    ["name" => "A", "price" => 54],
    ["name" => "B", "price" => 102],
    ["name" => "C", "price" => 4],
    ["name" => "D", "price" => 76],
];

echo("UNSORTED <br>\n");
print_r($data);

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["price"] - $b["price"];
});
echo("\n<br>\n<br>SORTED <br>\n");
print_r($data);
```

If you would like to order by names (or other string), you can use [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) for example.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted Up.

Comment: Is this what you've been lookin for?