# Sort multidimentional array PHP by ids

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Im trying to sort an multidimentional array based on a array in the order i would like it to appear in.

the `$lookingfor` array contains the order i would like it to appear, while `$avaliableArray` contains the whole multidimentional array. Would like the result in the example code called `$resultarray`

How would i do this, based on the `id` of the elements in `$avaliableArray` ?

code:

```
$avaliableArray = array(       
         array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-1"),
                array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-4"),

                array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-8")
);


$lookingFor = array(1,8,4);
```

looking for result:

```
$resultArray = array(       
         array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-1"),
                array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-8"),

                array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-4")
);
```

Comment: you can use `array_multisort` or `usort`.... There are lots of question like this.

Comment: It could be 1-8,2 so order by that i think wont work.

Comment: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) and so on...

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? The questions linked by @FrayneKonok are not similar (`$lookingFor` is the significant thing here)

Comment: @ChrisLear The first portion is same `testid-*` so why not this work with what i linked???

Comment: @ChrisLear, Why you blame me?? Do you think here is my fault???

Comment: @FrayneKonok it seems to me that you haven't seen the significance of the `$lookingFor` array. The two non-accepted answers also miss this.

Comment: @ChrisLear, What `usort` did? do your know?

Comment: @FrayneKonok I don't understand your question. But I know that the accepted answer solves the OP's problem using `usort`, taking some liberties with the original code, but getting the logic right. The essential thing is that it uses `$lookingFor` within the `usort` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `usort()` and apply proper id to `$lookingFor` same as array value.

```
$avaliableArray = array(       
         array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-1"),
                array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-4"),

                array('name' => 'Banken', 'site' => 'bank', 'avaliable' => true, 'type' => 'site', 'id' => "testid-8")
);


$lookingFor = array("testid-1","testid-8","testid-4");
usort($avaliableArray, function ($a, $b) use ($lookingFor) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['id'], $lookingFor);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['id'], $lookingFor);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($avaliableArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banken
            [site] => bank
            [avaliable] => 1
            [type] => site
            [id] => testid-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banken
            [site] => bank
            [avaliable] => 1
            [type] => site
            [id] => testid-8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banken
            [site] => bank
            [avaliable] => 1
            [type] => site
            [id] => testid-4
        )

)
```

Comment: thnks for suggestion. Changed it. @FrayneKonok

Comment: `$lookingFor = array(1,8,4);` is the correct form. 1 - 8 - 4

Comment: right, I have changed it accordingly. thx again. :) @FrayneKonok

Answer (score 0):

You should try usort :

```
function sortIt($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['id'],$b['id']);
}

usort($resultArray, 'sortIt');
```

Comment: This doesn't use `$lookingFor` at all, so can't be right

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sortArr($a, $b) {
    return intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $a['id']), 10) - intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $b['id']), 10) ; // it will extract number from string and compare it
}

usort($avaliableArray, 'sortArr');
```

Comment: This doesn't use `$lookingFor` at all, so can't be right