# Sort Multidimensional Array By Searched Word

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort a multidimensional array by a searched keyword.
My array is like below.

```
<?php
array(
  array(
    'name'    => '11th-Physics',
    'branch'  => 'Plus One',
    'college' => 'Plus One',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'JEE-IIT',
    'branch'  => 'Physics',
    'college' => 'IIT College',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'Physics',
    'branch'  => 'Bsc Physics',
    'college' => 'College of Chemistry',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'Chemical Engineering',
    'branch'  => 'Civil',
    'college' => 'Physics Training Center',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'Physics Education',
    'branch'  => 'Mechanical',
    'college' => 'TBR',
  ),
)
?>
```

I need to sort this array when search keyword is `physics` . And after Sorting i need the result like below.

> NEEDED RESULT

```
<?php
array(
  array(
    'name'    => 'Physics',
    'branch'  => 'Bsc Physics',
    'college' => 'College of Chemistry',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'Physics Education',
    'branch'  => 'Mechanical',
    'college' => 'TBR',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => '11th-Physics',
    'branch'  => 'Plus One',
    'college' => 'Plus One',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'JEE-IIT',
    'branch'  => 'Physics',
    'college' => 'IIT College',
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'Chemical Engineering',
    'branch'  => 'Civil',
    'college' => 'Physics Training Center',
  ),
)

?>
```

That is I need to sort the array first by the `name` which is exactly like  the searched keyword. Then wildcard search in `name`. Then to the next key `branch` and same as above. Is there any php function to sort this array like my requirement. I have already checked `asort`, `usort`. But I didn't  get result properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: @WilliamPerron That is sort by key. I need to sort by Value with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call this simple function I just created for your requirement, It works just fine :) change the priority order according to your need

```
function sortArray($array,$itemToSearch)
{
    $sortedArray = array();
    $priorityOrder = ['name','branch','college'];

    foreach ($priorityOrder as $key) 
    {
        foreach ($array as $i => $value) 
        {
            if(strpos(strtolower($value[$key]), strtolower($itemToSearch)) === 0)
            {
                array_push($sortedArray, $value);
                unset($array[$i]);
            }
        }
        foreach ($array as $i => $value) 
        {
            if(strpos(strtolower($value[$key]), strtolower($itemToSearch)) > 0)
            {
                array_push($sortedArray, $value);
                unset($array[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome Baji. Thanks. Its working Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## Here we go

So I started from the algorithm in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) and modified it to fit your requirements. Since you have three different "priorities" to you sorting, we have to use some temporary variables to separate the elements we wish sorted.

```
// arrays used to separate each row based on the row where the word "Physics" is found
$searchName = array();
$searchBranch = array();
$searchCollege = array();

// arrays used later for array_multisort
$foundInName = array();
$foundInBranch = array();
$foundInCollege = array();

foreach ($var as $key => $row) {
    if(strpos(strtolower($row['name']), 'physics') !== false) {
        $searchName[$key]  = $row['name'];
        $foundInName[] = $row;
    }
    elseif(strpos(strtolower($row['branch']), 'physics') !== false) {
        $searchBranch[$key]  = $row['branch'];
        $foundInBranch[] = $row;
    }
    elseif(strpos(strtolower($row['college']), 'physics') !== false) {
        $searchCollege[$key]  = $row['college'];
        $foundInCollege[] = $row;
    }
}

// Note: I use SORT_NATURAL here so that "11-XXXXX" comes after "2-XXXXX"
array_multisort($searchName, SORT_NATURAL, $foundInName);      // sort the three arrays separately
array_multisort($searchBranch, SORT_NATURAL, $foundInBranch);
array_multisort($searchCollege, SORT_NATURAL, $foundInCollege);

$sortedArray = array_merge($foundInName, $foundInBranch, $foundInCollege);
```

Outputting `$sortedArray` using `var_dump()` gives something like:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(12) "11th-Physics"
        ["branch"]=> string(8) "Plus One"
        ["college"]=> string(8) "Plus One"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(7) "Physics"
        ["branch"]=> string(11) "Bsc Physics"
        ["college"]=> string(20) "College of Chemistry"
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(17) "Physics Education"
        ["branch"]=> string(10) "Mechanical"
        ["college"]=> string(3) "TBR"
    }
    [3]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(7) "JEE-IIT"
        ["branch"]=> string(7) "Physics"
        ["college"]=> string(11) "IIT College"
    }
    [4]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(20) "Chemical Engineering"
        ["branch"]=> string(5) "Civil"
        ["college"]=> string(23) "Physics Training Center"
  }
}
```

As you can see `11th-Physics` comes out first. That is because the `ASCII` value of numbers is lower than that of letters. To fix this, modify the `$search...` arrays by prepending a high `ASCII` character before the string.

```
if(strpos(strtolower($row['name']), 'physics') !== false) {
    // if the first character is a number, prepend an underscore
    $searchName[$key]  = is_numeric(substr($row['name'], 0, 1)) ? '_'.$row['name'] : $row['name'];
    $foundInName[] = $row;
}
```

Which yields the following output:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(7) "Physics"
        ["branch"]=> string(11) "Bsc Physics"
        ["college"]=> string(20) "College of Chemistry"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(17) "Physics Education"
        ["branch"]=> string(10) "Mechanical"
        ["college"]=> string(3) "TBR"
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(12) "11th-Physics"
        ["branch"]=> string(8) "Plus One"
        ["college"]=> string(8) "Plus One"
    }
    [3]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(7) "JEE-IIT"
        ["branch"]=> string(7) "Physics"
        ["college"]=> string(11) "IIT College"
    }
    [4]=> array(3) {
        ["name"]=> string(20) "Chemical Engineering"
        ["branch"]=> string(5) "Civil"
        ["college"]=> string(23) "Physics Training Center"
    }
}
```

---

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f94ca8f8953df391f5faaee4e854b8e7e378d28a)!