# Sort multidimensional array by given key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that needs to be reoreder, the array look like this :

```
[products] => Array
                    (
                    [149] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Ichikami1
                            [qty] => 2
                        )

                    [150] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Ichikami2
                            [qty] => 4
                        )

                    [377] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => BCL
                            [qty] => 2
                        )

                )
```

inside the child array there is 'qty' index, i want to sort the child array by 'qty' index  in descending order, so it will look like this:

```
[products] => Array
                    (

                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Ichikami2 
                                [qty] => 4
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Ichikami1 
                                [qty] => 2
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => BCL 
                                [qty] => 2
                            )

                    )
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Have you went through, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)?

Comment: post sample code you tried

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using [array_multisort()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), You can do this like:

```
$qty = array();
foreach ($products as $key => $row)
{
    $qty[$key] = $row['qty'];
}
array_multisort($qty, SORT_DESC, $products);
```