# How to sort multidimensional array ascending

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Now it only sort by a country name, but I also want to sort by room name as well. How can I do that?

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/RfMsE)

```php
$MainArray =  array('PHILIPPINES' => 
                    array(
                        'SUPERIOR KING ROOM' => array(
                            '2021-12-05' => array('total' => 1, 'revenue' => 600.00),
                            '2021-12-06' => array('total' => 4, 'revenue' => 534.00),
                        ),
                        '3D KING ROOM' => array(
                            '2021-12-05' => array('total' => 3, 'revenue' => 320.00),
                            '2021-12-06' => array('total' => 1, 'revenue' => 0.00)
                        ),
                    ),
                'AUSTRALIA' => 
                    array(
                        'PRESIDENTIAL SUITE' => array('2021-12-05' => array('total' => 4, 'revenue' => 888.00)),
                        'DELUXE ROOM' => array('2021-12-06' => array('total' => 1, 'revenue' => 0.00)),
                    ),
                );

/* sort by country name */
foreach ($MainArray as $key => $country){
    $ord[] = $key;
}
array_multisort($ord, SORT_ASC, $MainArray);
print_r($MainArray);
```

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16788610/1526406

Comment: is the country name key in the array and you want to sort with that key and then room name?

Comment: @PHPGeek no, it just display the name only. Yes, I want to sort with that key then follow up with the 'room name'

Comment: both the country and room names are keys. right?

Comment: @PHPGeek correct

Comment: try this code with your array.

$ord = array_keys($MainArray);
array_multisort($ord, SORT_ASC, $MainArray);
$array = [];
foreach ($MainArray as $key => $country) {
    $keys = array_keys($country);
    array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $country);
    $array[$key] = $country;
}
print_r($array);