# Sort Nested Array base on Value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array Like this

```
 $array = [
        [
            'project_id' => 1,
            'Client' => [
                ['Name' => 'Franco',
                'Amount' => 1000.00,
                 ],
                 ['Name' => 'Allan',
                'Amount' => 1000.00,
                ],
                ['Name' => 'Booby',
                'Amount' => 1000.00,
                ]
            ],
          
        ],
      
    ];
```

I use array_multisort and array_map to sort it by Name in descending, I already tried usort but still not working.. Any Help will be Appreciated

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        static function ($element) {
            return $element['Client']['Name'];
        },
        $array
    ),
    SORT_DESC,
    $array
);

return $array;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. However from your try what I can understand is you are trying to sort the client array based on 'Name'. So to achieve this please try the below logic with the same usort.

```
$array = [
    [
        'project_id' => 1,
        'Client' => [
            [
                'Name' => 'Franco',
                'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ],
            [
                'Name' => 'Allan',
                'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ],
            [
                'Name' => 'Booby',
                'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

usort($array[0]['Client'], function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
});

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a function I found from php documentation:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Not a Pro
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Sort Nested Array base on Value in PHP
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419733/sort-nested-array-base-on-value-in-php
Tags: php, arrays

*/


// Author: jimpoz at jimpoz dot com
// URL: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#100534
function array_orderby()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $data = array_shift($args);
    foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
        if (is_string($field)) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $row)
                $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
            $args[$n] = $tmp;
            }
    }
    $args[] = &$data;
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
    return array_pop($args);
}

function sortProjectsByClientName(&$projects)
{
    foreach ($projects as &$project) {
        $project['Client'] = array_orderby($project['Client'], 'Name', SORT_ASC);
    }
}

$projects = [
    [
        'project_id' => 1,
        'Client' => [
            ['Name' => 'Franco',
            'Amount' => 1000.00,
             ],
             ['Name' => 'Allan',
            'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ],
            ['Name' => 'Booby',
            'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ]
        ],
      
    ],
    [
        'project_id' => 2,
        'Client' => [
            ['Name' => 'Bob',
            'Amount' => 1000.00,
             ],
             ['Name' => 'Trevor',
            'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ],
            ['Name' => 'Alice',
            'Amount' => 1000.00,
            ]
        ],
      
    ]
];

sortProjectsByClientName($projects);
var_dump($projects);
```

Yields:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["project_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Client"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(5) "Allan"
        ["Amount"]=>
        float(1000)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(5) "Booby"
        ["Amount"]=>
        float(1000)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(6) "Franco"
        ["Amount"]=>
        float(1000)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["project_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["Client"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(5) "Alice"
        ["Amount"]=>
        float(1000)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(3) "Bob"
        ["Amount"]=>
        float(1000)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(6) "Trevor"
        ["Amount"]=>
        float(1000)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner using [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
array_multisort( 
    array_column(
        $array[0]['Client'] , 
        'Name' 
        ),
    SORT_DESC, 
    $array[0]['Client']
    );
```

Output:

```
Array(
 [0] => Array(
   [project_id] => 1
   [Client] => Array(
     [0] => Array(
       [Name] => Franco
       [Amount] => 1000
       )
     [1] => Array(
       [Name] => Booby
       [Amount] => 1000
     )
    [2] => Array(
       [Name] => Allan
       [Amount] => 1000
     )
   )
 )
)
```

If you have multiple elements in `$array` that have to be sorted by client, you can use [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) around the sort (it's still a one liner):

```
array_walk( 
    $array,
    function (&$a){
        return array_multisort( 
        array_column(
            $a['Client'] , 
            'Name' 
            ),
        SORT_DESC, 
        $a['Client']
        );
    }
);
```